# How to have data accessible from one android app's database to another app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-databinding

My first android app stores all data in an SQLite database and acts as a backend/admin panel.             What I require is to have this data accessible(readable) by my 2nd android app.

Is it possible via Data Binding or Content Providers? If yes then how, please provides example code.

Looking forward to credible guidelines.

Comment: AIDL concept in android can help u achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContentProvider` is what you need.

It let's you define a SQL like interface to your data.
You can query, update, insert, delete data.
You can define, which permission scope is allowed to access the data and so on.

In most cases it's just a wrapper around your `SQLiteDatabase`.

A good example for a `ContentProvider` is the sms or contacts database, accessible via `content://sms/...` or similar UIRs.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Can I use a ContentProvider for 2 different apps? Or I can just use it within a single app?

Comment: You can define the scope. In the `AndroidManifest.xml` is defined, if the `ContentProvider` is exported (accessible by other apps) or not. Additionally there is an permission model to make it more granular.

Comment: Correct! Done it with this excellent tutorial here: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.Uwwyr_mSw50